# JavaScript function with PHP code not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have a form with JavaScript and PHP validation. One of the form's features is a JavaScript function that copies a DIV and adds it to the page. The copy function works without any problems and the PHP and Javascript validation work for the initial DIV.

**The problem:**
The PHP validation doesn't work for the newly created DIV's.

In other words, I have a DIV that is copied with a JavaScript function and has some PHP code. The problem is with the PHP code that only works for the initial DIV and not the new created DIV's.

This is the HTML code that is copied:

```
<div id="addinput">

<p> lorem 
   <input onBlur="data(this)" type="text"  id="valA" name="valA" 
    value="<?php   echo  ($valA);?>"/> 
   <span><?php echo $valAErr;?></span> 

    <select id="valD" name="valD" size="1">
       <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
       <option value="valueA">A</option>
       <option value="valueB">B</option> 
    </select>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $valDErr;?></span> 

    <a href="#" id="addNew">Add</a>
</p>
</div>
```

This is the initial JavaScript function that copies the DIV. This was made before I added the PHP code in the Javascript function and the HTML code, and it worked.

```
$(function() {
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;
$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p> lorem 
       <input onBlur="data(this)" type="text" id="valA" name="valA' + i +'" 
        value=""/>


        <select id="valD" name="valD' + i +'" name="tip" size="1">
           <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
           <option>A</option>
           <option>B</option>
        </select>

        <a href="#" id="remNew">Delete</a> 
</p>').appendTo(addDiv);

i++;

return false;
});

$('#remNew').live('click', function() {
if( i > 2 ) {
$(this).parents('p').remove();
i--;
}
return false;
});
});
```

This is my JavaScript code with PHP and it doesn't work:

```
$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p>lorem

      <input onBlur="data(this)" type="text" id="valA" name="valA' + i +'" 
       value="<?php echo ($valA);?>"/>
      <span class="eroareData, error"> <?php echo $valAErr;?> </span> 

      <select id="valD" name="valD' + i +'" name="tip" size="1">
            <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
      </select> 
      <span class="error"><?php echo $valCErr;?></span>
     <a href="#" id="remNew">Delete</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
```

Comment: You can't use JavaScript, a client-side language. And expect it to directly execute sever-side code. You are going to need to use AJAX.

Comment: Using the jQuery selector like this is something really nasty. It just doesn't make sense. Simplify it! Dear God...

Comment: Ok... Since I don't konw AJAX yet, that part of the form will have only javascript validation for now. Thank you very much

Comment: For Marco: no argument there, but how do you propose to use it? please add an example so I can understand better

Comment: The inline PHP code will be executed when the script is first rendered to the browser, not when you click on something. However, while I don't fully follow what you are doing I am not convinced you need PHP/server side at all. Copying divs can be done in pure jQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to work to make this a better question. Trim the code to the bare essential of what you're doing. It may take time, but it'll be useful experience, and if you ask a better question, we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry for not expalining better. I have problems when I try to validate the new DIV's that are created when an user click's the "Add" button. This is where the PHP code should work, but it only validates the original DIV and not the copies

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to add some error messages or something 
*(that's what i can make up of the code)*

Try validating it first in a block of php code, then make a string and dynamically add in the messages in there.

**PHP**

```
// Validation stuff here
$script_string = "<div>". $valDErr ."</div>";
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#addNew").click(function(event){
    $("#appendDiv").append("<?php echo $script_string; ?>");
});
```

Comment: Even better, do `append(<?php echo json_encode($script_string) ?>)`. That will add the quotes, and do any necessary escaping too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#addNew').on('click', function() { // live() is dead =)
    $('<p>De la <input onBlur="data(this)" type="text" id="valA" name="valA' + i +'" value="' + <?php echo $valA; ?> + '"/><span class="eroareData, error">' + <?php echo $valAErr; ?> + '</span> pana la <input onBlur="data2(this)" type="text" id="valB" name="valb' + i +'" value="' + <?php echo $valB; ?> + '"/><span class="eroareData2' + i +', error">' + <?php echo $valBErr; ?> + '</span> la pretul de <input onBlur="numar2(this)" type="text" id="valC" name="valC' + i +'" value="' + <?php echo $valC; ?> + '" /> <span class="eroareNumere2' + i +', error">' + <?php echo $valCErr; ?> + '</span> LEI pe <select id="valD" name="valD' + i +'" name="tip" size="1"><option selected disabled hidden value=''></option><option value="zi">zi</option><option value="samptamana">samptamana</option><option value="luna">luna</option></select> <a href="#" id="remNew">Sterge</a> </p>').appendTo(addDiv);
});
```

PHP will be executed before your JavaScript so you don't need to escape the double quotes... I just added some JavaScript concat for code readibility... Hopes this help

Comment: I tried the on('click') function, but it doesn't work. When I put the live function, it works. Any ideas as to why? :)

Comment: what's your jquery version? the `on()` method appears with jQuery1.7

Comment: Good idea. I updated the JQuery version to  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and the on('click function') works. Oddly, it only works for the add button and not the delete button even though I updated both of them